# Select all sibling elements, not just following ones

Tags: css, css-selectors

The intent is to target all the other elements of the same type & same level whenever one is hovered. Tried

```
a:hover ~ a
```

Only to notice that this doesn't target the elements before the hovered one... Is there a solution with css? Or should I just somehow js my way out of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variation on the `parent` or `<` selector question ([of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795047/css-parent-or-this-selector) [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873755/css-parent-of-selector) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516504/css3-selector-select-a-parent-node-of-a-specific-node)). I know it's not quite the same, but I'm sure you can imagine how a sibling selector would be derived from a parent selector.

Jonathan Snook has an [excellent blog post](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors/) on why this doesn't exist, and I don't think I can do any better, so I'll leave you to read that if it interests you. Basically, it's a technically difficult job because of the way elements are selected, and it would lead to a whole world of mess in terms of code structure.

So the short answer is, this doesn't exist and you'll need to resort to JS to fix it, I'm afraid.

**Edit:** Just a couple of examples of fixes. Using jQuery:

```
$(selector).siblings().css({...});
```

or if you want to include the element:

```
$(selector).parent().children().css({...});
```

Or in vanilla JS:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // or getElementById or whatever
var siblings = element.parentNode.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
    if (siblings[i] !== element) { // optional
        siblings[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for the vanilla JS part, replace `i = siblings.length` by `i < siblings.length` to avoid enless loop. Also you can add a test like `nodes[i] instanceof HTMLLIElement` to select only HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using jQuery to toggle the hover states instead of CSS:

HTML:

```
​<div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
div a {color: #000;}
div a.hover {color: #00f;}
```

​
jQuery:

```
$("div a").hover(
    function(){
        $("div a").addClass("hover");
    },
    function(){
        $("div a").removeClass("hover");
    }
);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDUqS/)

Comment: I think `$(this).siblings()` or `$(this).parent().children()` (depending on whether you want to include `this`) is better, as it decouples the action from the selector.